# Does a windmill generator spin faster or slower if no power is being tapped from it?

Tags: power, generator

Title says it all. I can imagine it spinning faster because the energy that would be driving the generator isn't being tapped. But I could also imagine a scenario where a safety mechanism might prevent if from turning at full speed while the generator is disconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small fixed-pitch windmill will rotate fastest when there’s no load.  However, larger wind turbines have variable pitch blades that are adjusted so as to extract the maximum amount of energy for a given wind speed.  On windy days the limiting factor is that the blade tips need to be kept subsonic (at around 20-30rpm for large turbines) otherwise the noise level increases significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Small fixed-pitch windmills are fixed to the generator: there is no way to disconnect the generator. To prevent over-spinning, the generator is switched to a dump load when there is no other load available.

Small fixed-pitch windmills may be able to turn side-on when the wind is too fast, which is another way of regulating speed, but that is generally tuned for different conditions than the dump-regulation, which may be required at low wind speed.